# If the date field is empty, do not save anything in the database

Tags: php, wordpress

When the user leaves the date field empty and saves it, the date will be displayed as 03-20-0621 in the database, if it should be empty. I use the [Parsi Date](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-parsidate/) plugin that converts Gregorian dates to jalali(shamsi). The following code stores the date in Gregorian format in the database :

```
/**
 *  This filter is applied to the $value before it is saved in the db
 *
 * @param           $value (mixed) the value found in the database
 * @param           $post_id (mixed) the $post_id from which the value was loaded
 * @param           $field (array) the field array holding all the field options
 *
 * @return          false|string $value
 * @since           4.0.0
 */
function update_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    if ( ! wpp_is_active( 'acf_persian_date' ) ) {
        $value = gregdate( 'Y-m-d', $value );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wpp_acf_before_update_jalali_date', $value );
}
```

But there is no condition that if the date field is empty, don't save anything in the database. I used the following code to edit the function, but the date is stored as 0621-03-20 in the database if the date field is empty.

```
function customize_update_value( $value ) {
    if ( ! empty( $value ) ) { return $value; }
} add_filter( 'wpp_acf_before_update_jalali_date', 'customize_update_value', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Friends, there is no one to help? `if ( empty( $value ) ) { return $value; }`, If I put this value in the first code that is inside the plugin itself, it works properly, but I don't want to touch the plugin files and do it through the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (  $value !='1970-01-01' ) { return $value; }
```

instead of

```
  if ( ! empty( $value ) ) { return $value; }
```